# How do I get Apache JMeter to include a GET or POST parameter in its CSV log output?

Tags: jmeter

I am performing HTTP Request samples (both GET and POST) in JMeter and am trying to figure out how to include pieces of the request (right now, just the query and form parameters) in the CSV log output.  It seems like I'll have to use something like BeanShell Listener to write my own log file using the JMeter API.  Does that sound right?

References:

- http://qainsights.com/how-to-write-data-to-excel-csv-in-jmeter-using-beanshell-scripting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Given your parameters are in form of [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (if not - you can convert them via [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) test element) you can use `samples_variable` property in order to add values to JMeter's .jtl results file

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (it's located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=var1,var2,etc.
   ```

   where `var1` and `var2` are your JMeter Variables
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Next time you run your test variable values will be added to .jtl results file

References:

- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) chapter of JMeter [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) - comprehensive information on JMeter Properties and ways of working with them

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that.  If I were to attempt to recreate my own CSV log using BeanShell, however, do you know how would I go about grabbing the fields such as "elapsed", "label", and "responseCode"?  I'm looking at the JMeter API to see how to access them, but the answer eludes me.  BTW, your user.properties solution will definitely work in this case, but I am just questioning the wisdom of putting fields in the user.properties for tests that will only apply to a small number of our systems.

Comment: I'm making some progress.  `sampleResult.getSamplerData()` gives me the request data.  Am working on the rest of the data, most importantly the response time, etc.  I think `sampleResult.getTime()` does that, but I haven't been able to write that out to a file.  I think my logger is choking on its data type.  `sampleResult.getResponseCode()` and `sampleResult.getResponseMessage()` are working.

Comment: You can choose what to store in results file manipulating properties as well. Check out `jmeter.properties` file, look for properties which names start with `jmeter.save.saveservice`. Override those you need in `user.properties` file. If you need to store everything separately you can use i.e. [FileUtils.writeStringToFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) method. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for details.